# How to enable Menu screen option CSS Classes by default?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

[image: Menu screen option]

I want to enable the menu screen option `CSS classes` by default.
What code should I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a filter to `get_user_option_{$option}` where `{$option}` is the user meta key `managenav-menuscolumnshidden` checked in the `wp_nav_menu_setup()` function. If the meta value is `false`, which it will be the first time a user logs in, it sets the default hidden options. If you hook into this, you can set your own default values and make sure it never returns `false`.

```
// add a filter to catch unset hidden options
add_filter( 'get_user_option_managenav-menuscolumnshidden', 'my_default_menuscolumnshidden', 99, 3 );
function my_default_menuscolumnshidden( $result, $option, $user_id ){
    if( $option == "managenav-menuscolumnshidden" ){
        // remove this function to prevent a loop
        remove_filter( 'get_user_option_managenav-menuscolumnshidden', 'my_default_menuscolumnshidden', 99 );
        // check if it is false (first login)
        $result = get_user_option( $option );
        if ( false === $result ) {
            // update with your own defaults (omits CSS from the hidden options)
            $result = array( 0 => 'link-target', 1 => 'xfn', 2 => 'description' );
            update_user_option($user->ID, 'managenav-menuscolumnshidden',
                $result,
                true);
        }
        // re-add filter in case it gets called again
        add_filter( 'get_user_option_managenav-menuscolumnshidden', 'my_default_menuscolumnshidden', 99 );
    }
    // if this was false before, now it is set to custom defaults
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I know this is a pretty old post, but I just wanted to add a small correction: the add_filter method takes 4 arguments. The 4th one being the number of arguments expected. This defaults to 1. It should be added to the example code, otherwise the `$options` won't be filled.

Comment: Good call - never actually ran this code. I'll update the answer here but feel free to propose edits yourself as well if you see a bug in an answer.